# SQL запрос

Tags: sql, mysql

Итак, проблема, собственно, в следующем.
Положим есть некие записи в таблице разных типов с неким индикатором:

- type, ind
- 0, 1
- 1, 1
- 0, 2
- 1, 0
- 0, 0
- 0, 0
- 1, 2
- 1, 0

Требуется следующее. Чтобы все индикаторы записи соответствующего типа, у которых в поле ind значение 0, продолжили инкрементироваться в зависимости от присутствующей информации о предыдущих записях такого же типа, т.е. предложенная выше таблица должна приобрести вид:

- type, ind
- 0, 1
- 1, 1
- 0, 2
- 1, 3
- 0, 3
- 0, 4
- 1, 2
- 1, 4

СУБД - MySQL. Боюсь ошибиться, но кажется ROW_COUNT() может не сработать (хотя может это был мой фейл с построением запроса)

Так или иначе, очень прошу помочь. Не хочется разбивать запросы и плодить кучу обращений к базе.

Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Забыл, что если необходимо, безусловно, можно добавить поле первичного ключа (id). Если это поможет, я только за.

Comment: а почему 

1, 3

?

Comment: потому что 1, 2 есть чуть ниже. это первая комбинация 1, 0, которая встретилась, у типа 1 уже была 1-ца и 2-ка, следовательно теперь надо поставить 3.

Comment: в четвёртой строчке точно

    1, 3

Comment: да, точно так.

если же совсем никак не получается составить запрос, хорошо, считайте, что инкрементируемые ячейки идут попорядку сверху вниз. Т.е. если встретилась запись some_type, 0, то это значит, что ниже уже не могут быть записи some_type, number != 0. Считайте так. Будет полегче

Comment: Я окончательно запутался.. 4 строчка не соответствует вышеприведённому описанию алгоритма. то, что написано ниже вообще выбило меня из колеи и ничего не объяснило )) можно привести алгоритм? блок-схему? что-то однозначно описывающее желаемый результат из исходного.

Comment: @luxor - объяснение из разряда, потому что голуби ушли на шаверму а кошка убежала, будет собака...

Я понял если бы на месте 1,3 стоялобы 1,2 т.к. до этого было только 1,1. Понял если бы Вы написали что в 1,0 Вы хотите поставить наименьшее свободное число из всей последовательности типа 1. Но вы пишете что:

    продолжили инкрементироваться в зависимости от присутствующей информации о предыдущих записях такого же типа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите поставить наименьшее свободное число из всей последовательности типа:

```
update table as t1 
set ind = (select min(fmin2) 
           from (select row_num as fmin2, 
                        row_num - t2.ind as fmin 
                 from (
                       select * 
                       from table as t3
                       where t3.type = t1.type 
                       and t3.ind <> 0 
                       order by t3.ind) as t2 
           where fmin <> 0) 
where t1.ind = 0
```

Остаётся только придумать как реализовать row_num.

Вот пара ссылок по этой теме:
[1](http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/), [2](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=220611)

Comment: Спасибо. Да, первоначально объяснил не очень я :)